# DEAP: make mutation probability depend on generation number

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, deap

I am using a genetic algorithm implemented with the DEAP library for Python. In order to avoid premature convergence, and to force exploration of the feature space, I would like the mutation probability to be high during the first generations. But to prevent drifting away from extremum once they are identified, I would like the mutation probability to be lower in the last generations. How do I get the mutation probability to decrease over the generations? Is there any built-in function in DEAP to get this done?

When I register a mutation function, for instance

```
toolbox.register('mutate', tools.mutPolynomialBounded, eta=.6, low=[0,0], up=[1,1], indpb=0.1)
```

the `indpb` parameter is a float. How can I make it a function of something else?

Comment: I am not particularly sure how DEAP does mutate, but I am sure its being called within your program i.e. deap.tools.mutGaussian(xx). Couldnt you use a step decrease of 1-prob for each generation step to determine when to trigger the mutate step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Callbackproxy](https://pypi.org/project/objproxies/#lazy-proxies) which evaluates function arguments each time they are called. I added a simple example where I modified the official DEAP [n-queen example](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/ga/nqueens.py)
 such that the mutation rate is set to `2/N_GENS` (arbitrary choice just to make the point).

Notice that Callbackproxy receives a lambda, so you have to pass the mutation rate argument as a function (either using a fully blown function or just a lambda). The result anyway is that each time the `indpb` parameter is evaluated this lambda will be called, and if the lambda contains reference to a global variable generation counter, you got what you want.

```
#    This file is part of DEAP.
#
#    DEAP is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
#    published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of
#    the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#    DEAP is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
#    GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
#
#    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#    License along with DEAP. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

import random
from objproxies import CallbackProxy
import numpy

from deap import algorithms
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

# Problem parameter
NB_QUEENS = 20
N_EVALS = 0
N_GENS = 1

def evalNQueens(individual):
    global N_EVALS, N_GENS
    """Evaluation function for the n-queens problem.
    The problem is to determine a configuration of n queens
    on a nxn chessboard such that no queen can be taken by
    one another. In this version, each queens is assigned
    to one column, and only one queen can be on each line.
    The evaluation function therefore only counts the number
    of conflicts along the diagonals.
    """
    size = len(individual)
    # Count the number of conflicts with other queens.
    # The conflicts can only be diagonal, count on each diagonal line
    left_diagonal = [0] * (2 * size - 1)
    right_diagonal = [0] * (2 * size - 1)

    # Sum the number of queens on each diagonal:
    for i in range(size):
        left_diagonal[i + individual[i]] += 1
        right_diagonal[size - 1 - i + individual[i]] += 1

    # Count the number of conflicts on each diagonal
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(2 * size - 1):
        if left_diagonal[i] > 1:
            sum_ += left_diagonal[i] - 1
        if right_diagonal[i] > 1:
            sum_ += right_diagonal[i] - 1

    N_EVALS += 1
    if N_EVALS % 300 == 0:
        N_GENS += 1
    return sum_,


creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)

# Since there is only one queen per line,
# individual are represented by a permutation
toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("permutation", random.sample, range(NB_QUEENS), NB_QUEENS)

# Structure initializers
# An individual is a list that represents the position of each queen.
# Only the line is stored, the column is the index of the number in the list.
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.permutation)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

toolbox.register("evaluate", evalNQueens)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxPartialyMatched)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutShuffleIndexes, indpb=CallbackProxy(lambda: 2.0 / N_GENS))
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)





def main(seed=0):
    random.seed(seed)

    pop = toolbox.population(n=300)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("Avg", numpy.mean)
    stats.register("Std", numpy.std)
    stats.register("Min", numpy.min)
    stats.register("Max", numpy.max)

    algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=0.5, mutpb=1, ngen=100, stats=stats,
                        halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    return pop, stats, hof


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How do you figure that there are 300 evaluations per generation?

Comment: well, that's a good point. I assumed that each individual is evaluated each generation and that is not necessarily the case. A better option would be to update the global N_GENS variable straight from the evolution loop, but that would require editing the eaSimple function or creating your own. Couldn't find a better way to do that yet.

Comment: The eaSimple prints out the number of evaluations on screen when it runs. Maybe there is a way of accessing that info and using it?

Comment: You can reassign sys.stdout to a file and then keep track of the lines printed on that file, although it sounds like a real overkill. I would just copy-past the eaSimple function and make the necessary adaptations.